# Padding issue on Nexus 7 tablet

Tags: android

I'm noticing some issues with padding on the Nexus 7 tablet running Android 4.1. Specifically, I have a background drawable with padding that creates a outer stroke:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

  <stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#59000000" />

  <padding
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" />

  </shape>
```

This is supplemented with a 1dp white inner stroke. So it should be a square 2 dp border around the entire image:

I have tested it on the actual nexus device and on several other devices and the 7 inch jelly bean emulator:

First, here is the working version from the 4.1 7 inch emulator:
[image: This is the 7 inch tablet emulator for 4.1]

The border around the outside is even and goes around the entire image. This is how it works on all the other devices i have as well.

Nexus 7:

[image: Image with messed up padding]

The gray is the background color, but you can see the right and bottom padding is not being respected. The border is being obscured by the the image now.

If it matters, these are children of a GridView. Wonder if anyone has seen these issues or has ideas on how to resolve them.

Comment: I can't help but think this is due to scaling, although with an XML drawable I'm not thinking it should matter... It's a stretch, but what folder is this drawable in? The Nexus 7 is `tvdpi` and not `mdpi`, so I'm inclined to think this is related somehow.

Comment: well, i had no idea that tvdpi even existed. I'm currently housing it in drawable-nodpi since i figured it was defined in xml without requiring scaling. I'm just baffled on why it would work in the emulator and not on the device.

Comment: Yeah, even Google recommends not worrying about tvdpi for the Nexus 7, but this definitely looks like a scaling issue. Try setting your emulator to 213 dpi (tvdpi density) and see if the issue presents itself.

Comment: Thats what it is set to by default when you select Built-in WXGA800-7in. Oh well, it seems like its a device specific issue at this point.

Comment: This is a rendering issue that will be fixed in a future release. Thanks for the report, and sorry. Note that it is *not* a scaling issue. The problem lies in how stroked rectangles are rendered with hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug when generating the `stroke` in the XML drawable. After multiple attempts, I've narrowed it down to that; it seems to be making the stroke size incorrectly on the lower and right sides of the shape, even if specified in pixels. If I simply change the stroke width to `2dip` instead of `1dip` (all other things staying as they are), this is the result:

[image]

This is the `border.xml`  I used for the background of the after image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#59000000"/>

    <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp"/>

</shape>
```

Which, again, is just yours with the stroke width enlarged. The good thing is, **this won't change the expected result at all** since the padding remains the same. In fact, you can change the `stroke` tag to `solid` and still have the same result (however, if your images contain transparency you'd see the solid background in the transparent areas).

Give this a try; let me know how it works for you!

Comment: This did work for me, why it worked is baffling :) But it does work, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. :) I'm glad it worked, but I also wish I knew exactly why.